# Command line error D8036 - not allowed with multiple source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I was working in visual studio, and I made a few changes to one of my projects (changed a few include directories). When I tried to build that project later on I got the following error message:

```
cl : Command line error D8036: '/Fo.\obj\ms100_r' not allowed with multiple source files
```

I don't see how that is relevant to what I changed at all. I even rolled my .vcxproj file back to the previous version and that error still persists. I am clueless as to what is causing it. Aren't command line parameters supposed to be managed by visual studio anyway?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

had the same problem and realized i had removed the slash at the end of:

configuration properties->c/c++->output files->object file name->

once i added back the slash at the end of the file name, everything worked again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with /doc. For me the solution was to change Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Output Files | XML Documentation File Name from "$(TargetPath).xml" to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

this error due invalid setting in project Browse information .
goto configuration > C/C++ > Browse information > Enable Browse Information   to None

Answer (score 0):

A twisted variation on the selected answer is if you use quotes around pathname.  The backslash *must* be the last character.

So:

```
/Fa"\base\some dir\" will fail
/Fa"\base\some dir"\ will work
```